# Combine multiple dict in a single list of dicts based on the key value matches in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I would like to combine multiple dict in a list of dicts based on multiple key/value matches.

To be precise: match key value "ru" & "code", if it matches combine the dict and add "usg_amt" of mutiple dict that matches.

***Input***

```json
{
    "cis": [
        {
            "Id": "388",
            "type": "usage",
            "properties": {
                "usg_amt": "144",
                "ru":"123.01",
                "code":"2236"
           }
        },
                                   {
            "Id": "389",
            "type": "usage",
            "properties": {
                "usg_amt": "82",
                "ru":"123.01",
                "code":"2236"
           }
        },
        {
            "Id": "19",
            "type": "usage",
            "properties": {
                "usg_amt": "12",
                "ru":"124.01",
                "code":"2235"
           }
        }
]
}
```

***Expected***

```json
{
    "cis": [
        {
            "Id": "388",
            "type": "usage",
            "properties": {
                "usg_amt": "226", ###### 82+144
                "ru":"123.01",
                "code":"2236"
           }
        },
        {
            "Id": "19",
            "type": "usage",
            "properties": {
                "usg_amt": "12",
                "ru":"124.01",
                "code":"2235"
           }
        }
]
}
```

***Code***

But the below code is only giving a single dict as output.

```yaml
 - name: Combine the dictionaries that have matching age
       set_fact:
          combined_list: "{{ datacreate.cis | combine({'key': ['ru', 'code']}) }}"
```

Comment: @Vladimir Botka It should be the sum of all dict usg_amt key value which are having the matching/same "ru" and "code". So there is a small typo in my exected section, the usg_amt should be 144+82, as both of the "ru" and "code" values are the same for these 2 dict.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka
Sorry i am unable to edit the question as it says there are too many edits pending. Not sure what is this about.

Comment: OK. I fixed it. `82+144=226`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Match attributes *`ru`* and *`code`*. If they match combine the dictionaries."***

A: Create the list of the indexes *cis_index* and [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the dictionaries

```yaml
  cis_index: "{{ cis|json_query(cis_index_query) }}"
  cis_index_query: '[].{index: join(`_`, [properties.ru, properties.code])}'
  cis_indexs: "{{ cis|zip(cis_index)|map('combine') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  cis_index:
  - index: '123.01_2236'
  - index: '123.01_2236'
  - index: '124.01_2235'
```

```yaml
  cis_indexs:
    - Id: '388'
      index: '123.01_2236'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '144'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '389'
      index: '123.01_2236'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '82'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '19'
      index: '124.01_2235'
      properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: '12'}
      type: usage
```

Group the items of the list by *index*

```yaml
  cis_groups: "{{ cis_indexs|groupby('index') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  cis_groups:
    - - '123.01_2236'
      - - Id: '388'
          index: '123.01_2236'
          properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '144'}
          type: usage
        - Id: '389'
          index: '123.01_2236'
          properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '82'}
          type: usage
    - - '124.01_2235'
      - - Id: '19'
          index: '124.01_2235'
          properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: '12'}
          type: usage
```

Create the expected structure in Jinja. Fit the template to your needs

```yaml
  cis_update_str: |
    {% for i in  cis_groups %}
    - {{ i.1|reverse|combine }}
    {% endfor %}
  cis_update: "{{ cis_update_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  cis_update:
    - Id: '388'
      index: '123.01_2236'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '144'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '19'
      index: '124.01_2235'
      properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: '12'}
      type: usage
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    cis:
      - Id: '388'
        properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '144'}
        type: usage
      - Id: '389'
        properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '82'}
        type: usage
      - Id: '19'
        properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: '12'}
        type: usage

    cis_index: "{{ cis|json_query(cis_index_query) }}"
    cis_index_query: '[].{index: join(`_`, [properties.ru, properties.code])}'
    cis_indexs: "{{ cis|zip(cis_index)|map('combine') }}"
    cis_groups: "{{ cis_indexs|groupby('index') }}"
    cis_update_str: |
      {% for i in  cis_groups %}
      - {{ i.1|reverse|combine }}
      {% endfor %}
    cis_update: "{{ cis_update_str|from_yaml }}"
    cis_updat2: "{{ cis_groups|map('last')|map('reverse')|map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: cis|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: cis_index
    - debug:
        var: cis_indexs|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: cis_groups|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: cis_update|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: cis_updat2|to_yaml
```

---

Q: ***"Sum all attributes `usg_amt`."***

A: Fit the template to your needs

```yaml
  cis_update_str: |
    {% for i in  cis_groups %}
    {% set usg_amt = i.1|map(attribute='properties.usg_amt')|map('int')|sum %}
    - {{ i.1|reverse|combine([{'properties': {'usg_amt': usg_amt}}], recursive=true) }}
    {% endfor %}
  cis_update: "{{ cis_update_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  cis_update:
    - Id: '388'
      index: '123.01_2236'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: 226}
      type: usage
    - Id: '19'
      index: '124.01_2235'
      properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: 12}
      type: usage
```

Use the filter [*ansible.utils.remove_keys*](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils/blob/main/docs/ansible.utils.remove_keys_filter.rst#ansibleutilsremove_keys) if you want to remove the attribute *index* from the result

---

Q: ***"This code is not adding the decimal values and it's ignoring all the `usg_amt` values which are having decimals."***

A: Fit the template to your needs

```yaml
    cis_update_str: |
      {% for i in  cis_groups %}
      {% set usg_amt_list = i.1|map(attribute='properties.usg_amt') %}
      {% set sum_float = usg_amt_list|select('search', '\.')|length > 0 %}
      {% if sum_float %}
      {% set usg_amt = usg_amt_list|map('float')|sum %}
      {% else %}
      {% set usg_amt = usg_amt_list|map('int')|sum %}
      {% endif %}
      - {{ i.1|reverse|combine([{'properties': {'usg_amt': usg_amt}}], recursive=true) }}
      {% endfor %}
    cis_update: "{{ cis_update_str|from_yaml }}"
```

Given the data to test *floats* (decimals)

```yaml
  cis:
    - Id: '388'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '144'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '389'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '82'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '19'
      properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: '12'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '20'
      properties: {code: '2237', ru: '125.01', usg_amt: '1.10'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '21'
      properties: {code: '2237', ru: '125.01', usg_amt: '1.20'}
      type: usage
```

Update the attribute `usg_amt` with *float* if any of the items is *float*

```yaml
  cis_update:
    - Id: '388'
      index: '123.01_2236'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: 226}
      type: usage
    - Id: '19'
      index: '124.01_2235'
      properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: 12}
      type: usage
    - Id: '20'
      index: '125.01_2237'
      properties: {code: '2237', ru: '125.01', usg_amt: 2.3}
      type: usage
```

In the input list *cis* the values of the attribute *usg_amt* are strings. If you want to keep the strings also in the updated list convert the integers, or floats to strings

```yaml
      - {{ i.1|reverse|combine([{'properties': {'usg_amt': usg_amt|string}}], recursive=true) }}
```

gives

```yaml
  cis_update:
    - Id: '388'
      index: '123.01_2236'
      properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '226'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '19'
      index: '124.01_2235'
      properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: '12'}
      type: usage
    - Id: '20'
      index: '125.01_2237'
      properties: {code: '2237', ru: '125.01', usg_amt: '2.3'}
      type: usage
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    cis:
      - Id: '388'
        properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '144'}
        type: usage
      - Id: '389'
        properties: {code: '2236', ru: '123.01', usg_amt: '82'}
        type: usage
      - Id: '19'
        properties: {code: '2235', ru: '124.01', usg_amt: '12'}
        type: usage
      - Id: '20'
        properties: {code: '2237', ru: '125.01', usg_amt: '1.10'}
        type: usage
      - Id: '21'
        properties: {code: '2237', ru: '125.01', usg_amt: '1.20'}
        type: usage

    cis_index: "{{ cis|json_query(cis_index_query) }}"
    cis_index_query: '[].{index: join(`_`, [properties.ru, properties.code])}'
    cis_indexs: "{{ cis|zip(cis_index)|map('combine') }}"
    cis_groups: "{{ cis_indexs|groupby('index') }}"
    cis_update_str: |
      {% for i in  cis_groups %}
      {% set usg_amt_list = i.1|map(attribute='properties.usg_amt') %}
      {% set sum_float = usg_amt_list|select('search', '\.')|length > 0 %}
      {% if sum_float %}
      {% set usg_amt = usg_amt_list|map('float')|sum %}
      {% else %}
      {% set usg_amt = usg_amt_list|map('int')|sum %}
      {% endif %}
      - {{ i.1|reverse|combine([{'properties': {'usg_amt': usg_amt|string}}], recursive=true) }}
      {% endfor %}
    cis_update: "{{ cis_update_str|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: cis|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: cis_index
    - debug:
        var: cis_indexs|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: cis_groups|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: cis_update|to_yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a response. Could you please help me with the request in the question, how to add the key "usg_amt" if the 'ru' & 'code' matches. for eg:  in your example, the ru value 123.01 and 'code' value 2236 should have a 'usg_amt' of 144+82 = 226. Appreciate your help

Comment: Excellent solution. I have just tested and everything is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing an issue, this code is not adding the decimal values and its ignoring all the "usg_amt" values which are having decimals. Can you help here?

Comment: I added an example.